# What is the purpose of Application class in Android

Tags: android

What exactly is the purpose of Application class. 
what are the benefits of extending it to a custom subclass
Why use it ?
Can global variables be stored in any other class achieve same goal as Application ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nice question !

Your application is a context that is always running while your activities and services are running.

It is also the first context to be created and the last to be destroyed.
Thus, it surrounds the life cycle of your app.

You can use the application class as a way to share data or components (for dependency injection for instance). For instance if you want to share a singleton between activities, you can create the instance in the application class and provide a getter, then all other contexts can get the singleton via

```
((cast to your class)getApplicationContext()).getFoo();
```

There may be some use cases where you need to do stuff before even your first activity is launched, then do it in the onCreate method of the application class.

On the other hand, you should never relie on the `onDestroy` method of the `Application` class, as it is not always called. There is no contract for that on Android.

But this is rare and, usually, you don't need to override the application class though. Dependency injection can be achieved in other ways by RoboGuice or Dagger for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Two things makes this Class very useful:

1. Application class is instantiated before any other Activity.
2. It holds the Application Context

Context brings a host of resources for us: we can figure out some device properties, load some resources, initiate a SQLite database etc, etc.

All of this happens before any Activity loads, and all of this is globally available to the Activities.

Simple example of what I mean:

```
public class App extends Application{
    private static Resources sResources;

    //--I want to load strings resources from anywhere--
    public static String loadStringResource(int resID) {
        return sResources.getString(resID);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sResources = getResources();

        //---I want to load all preferences when my app starts---
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.prefs,false);

    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the Application class is where all the native c/c++ libraries created for ndk are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the `Application` class allows you to integrate into the application's lifecycle.

This is also useful to store global application-level information (though it's usually good to keep your activities 'independent')

Answer (score 0):

The Application class is aware of the Application Context and is loaded when your app is loaded so it holds the proper callbacks for the application lifecycle before your activity starts. You most likely would not want to extend this class.

From the API docs:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html